# Create array of the duplicates from array containing duplicates in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, set

For an array of objects `["a","b","a","c","d","b"]` I'd like to get an array of the duplicates:
`["a","b"]`.

Is there a way to do this efficiently, similar to `set` (`[...new Set(myArray)];`)?

Comment: please add your try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could still use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and filter the array by checking the existence.

```js
const
    items = ["a", "b", "a", "c", "d", "b"],
    duplicates = items.filter((s => v => s.has(v) || !s.add(v))(new Set));

console.log(duplicates);
```

Comment: Won't work if there are more than 2 occurrences. `["a", "a", "a"]` returns `["a", "a"]`

Comment: @adiga, it just filters the first occurences.